# For each commit hash use git show

Tags: git, git-log

I need to log all my git commits for my teacher. He gave me the following example:

```
git log --pretty="%H" --author=you | while read commit_hash 
                                     do git show $commit_hash
                                     done > log.txt
```

I know that the "you" part needs to be my name and the git command works fine but after the pipe it returns with a greater than sign and doesn't do anything. I also understand that it should use every commit hash for the `git show` command. Any suggestions? I'm also using OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you need to indicate the shell that the command line continue on the next lines (with a trailing `\`):

```
git log --pretty="%H" --author=you | while read commit_hash \
                                     do git show $commit_hash \
                                     done > log.tx
```

Comment: @AdrianZ. for that, you would need `;` , as in: `while read commit_hash; do git show $commit_hash; done > log.tx` (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bash-for-loop-one-line-command/)

Comment: Thanks you. That worked perfect. Learned something new again.

Answer (score 1):

VonC's answer is correct with regards to handling newlines, but your initial approach over complicates things. You can  use `git log -p` instead of a combination of `git log` and `git show`:

```
git log -p --author=you > log.txt
```

Comment: @AdrianZ. forgot about the difference `log` and `show` handle the missing commit spec parameter. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a while loop, you could run

```
git log --author=you --patch --stat > log.txt
```